# BouncyCastle verify throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown object in getInstance: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERNull

Tags: java, bouncycastle, verify

I have following method

```
public static boolean verifSignedData(byte[] signedData, X509Certificate signercert) {
    boolean result = false;
    try {
        CMSSignedData cmsSignedData = new CMSSignedData(signedData);
        Collection<SignerInformation> signers = cmsSignedData.getSignerInfos().getSigners();
        X509CertificateHolder ch = new X509CertificateHolder(signercert.getEncoded());
        for (SignerInformation si : signers) {
            logger.info("AlgorithmId: {} serial: {}", si.getDigestAlgOID(), si.getSID().getSerialNumber());
            if (si.getSID().match(ch))
                if (si.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(ch)))
                    result=true;

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("",e);
    }
    return result;  
}
```

data and certificate seems to be ok (see output), but it throws an 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown object in getInstance: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERNull

```
2020-04-30 10:04:41,070 INFO  de.martinm.kks.PKCSTool: verifSignedData - AlgorithmId: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 serial: 4096
2020-04-30 10:04:41,210 ERROR de.martinm.kks.PKCSTool: verifSignedData -
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown object in getInstance: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERNull
        at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.AlgorithmIdentifier.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.OperatorHelper.notDefaultPSSParams(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.OperatorHelper.createSignature(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentVerifierProviderBuilder$1.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformationVerifier.getContentVerifier(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation.doVerify(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation.verify(Unknown Source)
        at de.martinm.kks.PKCSTool.verifSignedData(PKCSTool.java:98)
        at de.martinm.kks.PKCSTool.verify(PKCSTool.java:132)
        at de.martinm.kks.PKCSTool.process(PKCSTool.java:78)
        at de.martinm.kks.PKCSTool.main(PKCSTool.java:202)
2020-04-30 10:04:41,226 INFO  de.martinm.kks.PKCSTool: verify - verified: false
```

The exception is not thrown, when I use:

```
SignerInformationVerifier bcVerifier =
                            new BcRSASignerInfoVerifierBuilder(new DefaultCMSSignatureAlgorithmNameGenerator(),
                                          new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder(),
                                          new DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder(), 
                                          new BcDigestCalculatorProvider())
                            .build(new JcaX509CertificateHolder(signercert));
```

as SignerInformationVerifier.

But the signature verification fails with that code.

Comment: I've traced this through bouncycastle source code a little ways and it appears to me that this is a bug in bouncycastle. Specifically, in bcpkix ver 1.64 at line 580 in `org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.OperatorHelper`, the construction of the default algorithm ID is not correct. However, I'm no ASN.1 expert and this stuff is very confusing to me so I could be wrong. Also, I've never seen a certificate signed with RSA-PSS in the wild so perhaps this particular code path never got tested.

Comment: The Exception does not occur with version 1.54 but the verification of the signature does not succeed. Anyone an idea, how to get more information out of the verification process? There is a debug version of the provider but I cannot find any hint how to setup logging

Comment: The debug version of the provider is, as far as I know, simply compiled without optimization. There is no special logging functionality added. You should probably file a bug report. But it will help immensely to supply the certificate that is signed with RSA-PSS.

Comment: Ultimately, despite the superior cryptography involved, signing a certificate with RSA-PSS is probably a mistake, unless you really want to be the trailblazer that finds every other product's limitations and submits bug reports.

Comment: It was not my idea to use that algorithm